# Можно ли hover эффекту дать время, чтобы блок появился и стоял 5 секунд?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Можно ли `:hover` эффекту дать время, чтобы блок появился и стоял 5 секунд?

Answer (score 5):

Есть варианты (Обновляю. Спасибо @CbIPoK2513, я и забыл про анимацию, тоже вариант). Рассмотрите `transition` и `animation`. Этими способами можно добиться того о чем вы спрашиваете.

**Литература:**

[Псевдокласс :hover](https://webref.ru/css/hover)
[Свойство transition](https://webref.ru/css/transition)
[Свойство animation](https://webref.ru/css/animation)
[@keyframes](https://webref.ru/css/keyframes)

Answer (score 4):

```css
.block {width: 20px; height: 20px; background: green;}
.block:hover {
    background: red;
    animation-name: quadhide;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 5s; /*задержка*/
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes quadhide {
    to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: +1, отлично, это все не выпитое кофе с утра )))